# Trying to add specified content to a token returns 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty cannot have multiple values.'

Tags: c#, json.net

I added a new child to my **JObject**. That works.

```
var fi = e.PropertyA;
JObject o = JObject.FromObject(fi);
o.AddFirst(new JProperty("type", new JValue(fi.GetType().Name)));

// this works
o.Add("description", new JObject( new JProperty("de", new JValue("Wert"))));
var node = o.SelectToken("description");

if (node != null)
{
  // this fails
  // node.AddAfterSelf(new JProperty("en", "Value"));
}

"PropertyA": {
    "type": "SubObject",
    "Foo": "foo",
    "description": {
      "de": "Wert"
  }
}
```

After that I tried to add a new object to my previously created token. That fails with this error message:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonException: Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty cannot have multiple values

For reproducing that misbehaviour, please remove the comment in this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/h0wrnJ).

What I need is a internationalized JSON object like that.

One client will like to get the information in English

```
{
  "venue_id": "C001",
  "venue_location": "Baker St."
  "venue_name": "Aroma Coffee"
}
```

another client will like to get the information in Hebrew

```
{
  "venue_id": "C001",
  "venue_location": "רחוב האופה"
  "venue_name": "קפה ארומה"
}
```

The result should look like this

```
{
  "venue_id": "C001",
  "venue_location": {
    "en": "Baker St.",
    "he": "רחוב האופה"
  }
  "venue_name": {
    "en": "Aroma Coffee",
    "he": "קפה ארומה"
  }
}
```

described in [Approaches to JSON internationalisation (i18n)](https://www.drzon.net/posts/approaches-to-json-internationalisation-i18n/)

Comment: JObject essentially is a dictionary. so you can not add repetitive jproperty

Comment: Since a JProperty cannot have more than one value, when you try to add a JProperty immediately after the value in the hierarchy, you are trying to add it as a child of its parent JProperty, which throws the exception.

Comment: where this `e` comes from `var fi = e.PropertyA;` could you please add definition for this `e`

Comment: The code fragments above come from that [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/h0wrnJ).

If I add that new JProperty to the nodes parent than it looks like so

"PropertyA": {
    "type": "SubObject",
    "Foo": "foo",
    "description": {
      "de": "Wert"
    },
    "en": "Value"
  }

Comment: after analyzing your fiddle first you add JProperty  with name `type` to `JObject o`   then again you adding JProperty with name`description` to `JObject o`. till its fine but now your are selecting JProperty from `o.SelectToken("description")` then now  your `node` variable is of type JProperty and now you again trying add JProperty with name `en` to JProperty so how its possible? so for that declare one more JObject and assign this JObject to parent JObject

Comment: var node = o.SelectToken("description");
if (node != null)
{
  node.Parent.Add(new JObject(new JProperty("en", "Value")));
  //node.AddAfterSelf(new JProperty("en", "Value"));
}

results also in same error

Comment: @uwee, i'd just tried, no its not giving any error but its added new property after `description`

Answer (score 0):

So it works

```
o.Add("description", new JObject( new JProperty("de", new JValue("Wert"))));
var node = o.SelectToken("description") as JObject;
if (node != null)
{
    node.Add(new JProperty("en", "Value"));
}
```

results in

```
"PropertyA": {
    "type": "SubObject",
    "Foo": "foo",
    "description": {
      "de": "Wert",
      "en": "Value"
    }
}
```

@er-shoaib: Thanks for your effort